# How To Show Version Of Migrate Tool Installed

Tags: drush

Is there an Ubuntu (Linux) command line I can use to see current version of the Migrate Tool installed? I don't have access to the front end (admin/modules), just the back-end. I thought maybe some of the drush commands would work but I've not run into any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Drush [pm:list command](https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/pm_list/) shows the versions of all modules on a site.
- The Composer [show command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show-info) shows the versions of all code on a site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. I ran the below commands (first one, for the life of me, I can't get the path to stay) and I received what I needed. Thank you so much!!

export PATH="$(composer config -g home)/vendor/bin:$PATH"

cd /var/www/html/drupal10 && drush pm:list --type=module --no-core --status=enabled